# jQuery hsCountdown returns wrong values for some numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, countdown, var

I use rewrited hsCountdown library and for some numbers it show wrong values:
In example above I specified "130" for increment to, but `hsCountdown` incrementing it only to 125. **Why?**

I was debug for "r" variable (on line where located `#debug_console`) and what you can mean? This variable magically was increment not by integer number, but float.
For example, 54.0000000001 instead of 54. JavaScript, you're so drunk!

```js
(function(a) {
    "use strict";
    a.fn.hsCounter = function(b) {
        var c = a.extend({
            delay: 50,
            signPos: "after",
            classVisible: "countup-vis",
            decimalSeparator: ".",
            orderSeparator: " "
        }, b);
        return this.each(function() {
            b && a.extend(c, b);
            var timer, num, line, content, self = a(this),
                win = a(window),
                winTop = win.scrollTop(),
                winHeight = win.height(),
                numb = self.data("num"),
                increment = self.data("increment") ? self.data("increment") : (numb / 25 > 1.0 ? numb / 25 : 1.0),
                fractional = self.data("fractional") ? self.data("fractional") : 0,
                sign = self.data("sign") ? self.data("sign") : "",
                regExp = /(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g,
                start = self.data("start") ? +self.data("start") : 0,
                amount = a(".countup-amount"),
                realMaxNumber = numb - increment;

    winTop <= self.offset().top && winTop + winHeight >= self.offset().top && (timer = setTimeout(function u() {
     var currentIncrement = (fractional > 0 ? start.toFixed(fractional) : start);
     $('#debug_console').append('[Condition debug] (currentIncrement <= realMaxNumber) equals ('+currentIncrement+' <= '+realMaxNumber+')<br>');

     return (currentIncrement <= realMaxNumber)
     
     ?
     
     (start += increment, num = start.toFixed(fractional).replace(".", c.decimalSeparator).replace(regExp, "$1" + c.orderSeparator), content = self.find(amount).html(num), "after" == c.signPos ? self.html('<span class="countup-amount">' + num + '</span><span class="countup-sign">' + sign + "</span>") : "before" == c.signPos && self.html('<span class="countup-sign">' + sign + '</span><span class="countup-amount">' + num + "</span>"), self.hasClass("progress-up") && (self.html(self.html() + "<ins/>"), self.find("ins").css("width", start + "%")), self.parent().hasClass("countup-wrap") && (line = self.parent().find(".countup-line"), line.css("width", start + "%")), void(timer = setTimeout(u, c.delay)))
     
     :
     
     (start = numb, !0);
    }, c.delay));
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

function initCounter(a, b) { b ? a.hsCounter() : a.text("0"); }

initCounter($(".counterup"), 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="counterup js" data-num="130">...</h1>

<div id="debug_console"></div>
```

Comment: You had better make your code clean first and only then show it to us. It is almost impossible to read... Read about KISS))

Comment: What is hard to read, for example?

Comment: For example, variable names. Sorry, if I hurt your feelings. I didn't intend to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue relies in these lines:

`n = h.data("increment") ? h.data("increment") : (l / 25 > 1.0 ? l / 25 : 1.0),`
 and `t = l - n;`

`t` is basically the number that this code will count up to. `t` is calculated as `l` (which is the `data-num` attribute, 130 in this case minus `n` which is the derived from the `data-increment` attribute.

As you can see, you did not provide a `data-increment`, and the code defaults to `l / 25`, which is 130 / 25 = 5.2. Then, `t` is will actually be `l - n` = `130 - 5.2` = 124.8, and this is why it counts to 125 instead of 30.

A simple solution will be to add `data-increment="1"` to your `h1` tag. You can consider changing the default calculation for the `n` variable too.

**EDIT:**

I see that you edited your code, which is great because it's much easier to debug. I think the solution whould be to change this line: `(start = numb, !0);` to something like this: `self.find(".countup-amount").html(numb);` It basically means the if the current number + increment value is greater than the target value, it means it is the last step, and we can simply populate our `span` with the target value.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed JS code

```
(function(a) {
    "use strict";
    a.fn.hsCounter = function(b) {
        var c = a.extend({
            delay: 50,
            signPos: "after",
            classVisible: "countup-vis",
            decimalSeparator: ".",
            orderSeparator: " "
        }, b);
        return this.each(function() {
            b && a.extend(c, b);
            var timer, num, line, content, self = a(this),
                win = a(window),
                winTop = win.scrollTop(),
                winHeight = win.height(),
                numb = self.data("num"),
                fractional = self.data("fractional") ? self.data("fractional") : 0,
                decim = fractional > 0 ? 0.5 : 1.0,
                increment = self.data("increment") ? self.data("increment") : (numb / 25 > decim ? numb / 25 : decim),
                sign = self.data("sign") ? self.data("sign") : "",
                regExp = /(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g,
                start = self.data("start") ? +self.data("start") : 0,
                amount = a(".countup-amount");

                winTop <= self.offset().top && winTop + winHeight >= self.offset().top && (timer = setTimeout(function u() {
                    if ((fractional > 0 ? start.toFixed(fractional) : start) < numb) {
                        var stin = (start + increment > numb) ? (start = numb) : (start += increment);
                        return (stin, num = start.toFixed(fractional).replace(".", c.decimalSeparator).replace(regExp, "$1" + c.orderSeparator), content = self.find(amount).html(num), "after" == c.signPos ? self.html('<span class="countup-amount">' + num + '</span><span class="countup-sign">' + sign + "</span>") : "before" == c.signPos && self.html('<span class="countup-sign">' + sign + '</span><span class="countup-amount">' + num + "</span>"), self.hasClass("progress-up") && (self.html(self.html() + "<ins/>"), self.find("ins").css("width", start + "%")), self.parent().hasClass("countup-wrap") && (line = self.parent().find(".countup-line"), line.css("width", start + "%")), void(timer = setTimeout(u, c.delay)));
                    } else {
                        return (start = numb, !0);
                    }
                }, c.delay));
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

function initCounter(a, b) { b ? a.hsCounter() : a.text("0"); }

initCounter($(".counterup"), 1);
```